# Grails Acegi security: Problem with roles and access

Tags: security, grails, spring-security, user-roles

I'm having some strange behaviour in my application.

I've added a couple of fields to the User class (created by Acegi), so I can set an expired password, record last N passwords, stuff like that. We have 9 roles, `ROLE_ADMIN` being the "superuser" that can access all the functionality.

After deploying the app, users started complaining that they can't use it. They are able to login, but whenever they want to go somewhere, they get access denied, as if they didn't have the Role.

This happens on every User, except for the administrator (only has the `ROLE_ADMIN`), included those with (`ROLE_ADMIN` + other roles).

I can't even think where to start.

## Update

I've checked and user are coming from the database with the roles attached.

Roles are checked in the SecurityConfig.groovy file. I'm afraid that the problem is elsewhere, since I have a tagged version of the project that actually works.

Here's my SecurityConfig.groovy:

```
import com.mycompany.myapp.audit.Auditoria

security {

    // see DefaultSecurityConfig.groovy for all settable/overridable properties

    active = true

    loginUserDomainClass = "com.mycompany.myapp.user.User"
    authorityDomainClass = "com.mycompany.myapp.user.Role"
    requestMapClass = "com.mycompany.myapp.user.Requestmap"

    useRequestMapDomainClass = false

    /** authenticationEntryPoint */
    loginFormUrl = '/login/auth'
    forceHttps = 'false'
    ajaxLoginFormUrl = '/login/authAjax'
    authenticationFailureUrl = '/login/authfail'
    

    afterLogoutUrl = '/login/auth'

    requestMapString = """\
            CONVERT_URL_TO_LOWERCASE_BEFORE_COMPARISON
            PATTERN_TYPE_APACHE_ANT

            /=IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED
            /login/auth=IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
            /login/authajax=IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
            /login/authfail=IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
            /login/renew=IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
            /js/**=IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
            /css/**=IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
            /images/**=IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
            /plugins/**=IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
           
            
            /scan/uploadfile=IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
            /ticket/uploadfile=IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
            /analisis/list =ROLE_SUP_TECNICO, ROLE_OP_TECNICO, ROLE_OP_FUNCIONAL, ROLE_ADMIN
            /analisis/hazzards/**=ROLE_SUP_TECNICO, ROLE_OP_TECNICO, ROLE_OP_FUNCIONAL, ROLE_ADMIN
            /analisis/show/**=ROLE_SUP_TECNICO, ROLE_OP_TECNICO, ROLE_ADMIN
            /analisis/create/**=ROLE_SUP_TECNICO, ROLE_ADMIN
            /analisis/edit/**=ROLE_SUP_TECNICO,ROLE_ADMIN
            /hazzardsreport/**=ROLE_SUP_TECNICO, ROLE_OP_TECNICO, ROLE_OP_FUNCIONAL, ROLE_REPORTE_VULNERABILIDAD, ROLE_ADMIN
            /mistaken/**=ROLE_SUP_TECNICO, ROLE_OP_TECNICO, ROLE_ADMIN
            /hazzardtype/**=ROLE_SUP_TECNICO, ROLE_ADMIN

            /** MODULO NORMAS */
            /report/**=ROLE_OP_FUNCIONAL, ROLE_ADMIN
            /norm/**=ROLE_OP_FUNCIONAL, ROLE_ADMIN

            /** TICKETS */
            /ticket/**=ROLE_SUP_TECNICO, ROLE_OP_TECNICO, ROLE_ADMIN
            /alert/**=ROLE_SUP_TECNICO, ROLE_OP_TECNICO, ROLE_ADMIN
            /ticket/uploadfile=IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY

            /** RISKS */
            /project/**=ROLE_AN_RIESGOS, ROLE_ADMIN
            /riskreport/**=ROLE_AN_RIESGOS, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_REPORTE_RIESGO
            
        /** BUSINESS CONTINUITY*/
            /projectpcn/**=ROLE_AN_PCN, ROLE_ADMIN
        /businessuniteval/** = ROLE_AN_PCN, ROLE_ADMIN
        /subprocesseval/** = ROLE_AN_PCN, ROLE_ADMIN
        /failscenario/**=ROLE_AN_PCN, ROLE_ADMIN
        /strategy/**=ROLE_AN_PCN, ROLE_ADMIN
        /test/**=ROLE_AN_PCN, ROLE_ADMIN
        /reportepcn/**=ROLE_AN_PCN, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_REPORTE_PCN
        /process/**=ROLE_AN_PCN, ROLE_ADMIN
            
            
        /** ADMIN */
            /user/changeent=IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED
            /user/finduser=IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED
            /user/**=ROLE_ADMIN
            /role/**=ROLE_ADMIN
            /requestmap/**=ROLE_ADMIN
        /empresa/**=ROLE_ADMIN
        /asset/**=ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_SUP_TECNICO, ROLE_OP_TECNICO
        /responsable/**=ROLE_ADMIN
        /preference/**=ROLE_ADMIN
        /businessunit/**=ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_AN_PCN
                    
                    
            /**=IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED
        """


    useSecurityEventListener = true
   
    onInteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent = { e, appCtx ->
        Auditoria.log(e.getSource().getPrincipal().getDomainClass(), "Usuario autenticado - " + e.getSource().getDetails().getRemoteAddress())
    }

}
```

## Update - log verbosity and no comments/newlines

After updating my `SecurityConfig.groovy`, the error continues. However, I've retrived this log line. I tried to access `/norm/index` with a user that has all 9 roles assigned to them.

> DEBUG 28/Dec/2010 00:12:57,110
> [http-8080-3]  Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /norm/index; ConfigAttributes: [ROLE_OP_FUNCIONAL,ROLE_ADMIN]
>
> org.springframework.security.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor
>
> - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.providers.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@a00c7ad6:
>   Principal:
>   com.baufest.insside.security.UserLoginDetails@0:
>
> Username: someuser; Password:[PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true;
> AccountNonLocked: true; Granted
> Authorities: ROLE_OP_TECNICO;
> Password: [PROTECTED];
> Authenticated: true;
>
> Details: org.springframework.security.ui.WebAuthenticationDetails@0: Granted Authorities: ROLE_OP_TECNICO
>
> DEBUG 28/Dec/2010 00:12:57,110
> [http-8080-3]
> org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter
>
> - Access is denied (user is not anonymous); delegating to
>   AccessDeniedHandler

For what I read here, it seems that my User is only getting 1 role, even though when I debug it, user.authorities has all 9 roles assigned to it.

## Solution

Well, as it turns out, the `compareTo` method in my Role class (Role implements GrantedAuthority) was returning always 0. So each user had only one role (since they are stored in a Set).

Comment: Anything in application log? Do you have proper logs enabled? Do you have SecurityFilters.groovy, what is there?

Comment: try taking the comments out of the requestMapString.  Take the newlines out too.

Comment: I meant the extra newlines, not all newlines.  Put one entry per line.  Also, what URL are you trying to go to on login as a normal user...Finally, in your Config.groovy enable debug level logging on teh org.springframework.security package.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT --

from the [documentation](http://www.grails.org/AcegiSecurity+Plugin+-+Securing+URLs), the requestMapString should be of the form

```
requestMapString = '''CONVERT_URL_TO_LOWERCASE_BEFORE_COMPARISON 
                      PATTERN_TYPE_APACHE_ANT 
                      /login/**=IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY 
                      /admin/**=ROLE_USER
                      /book/test/**=IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY
                      /book/**=ROLE_SUPERVISOR
                   '''
```

a few notes:

1)  You have extra newlines and comments in the request map string.  The requestMapString is a [multiline String](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Strings+and+GString) (look at the '''one long string''' format), so the Acegi mechanisms are going to try and parse/use the comments.

Comment: What do you mean by "checking the roles correctly"? I wrote the mappings in the SecurityConfig.xml

Comment: @tom what do you mean you 'wrote the mappings' in SecurityConfig.xml.  It should be SecurityConfig.groovy.  Also, the url level checks in that mapping are just to whether an endpoint is secured at all.  You can still programmatically check for roles in your actions/service methods.  Since you didn't give that much information, i had to make assumptions on how you were using acegi

Comment: @hvgotcodes Sorry, I meant SecurityConfig.groovy. I got no programatic check, I thought that was all I needed.

Comment: @hvgotcodes I tried removing unnecesary newlines and comments, but still can't get access. It's kind of strange, theres a productive copy of a previous version of this file (with comments and newlines).

Comment: @tom, did you remove the comments?  Did you up the logging for security.

Comment: @tom, which url are you trying to access?

Comment: @tom, is that your entire security config?  Have you configured any voters/filters?

Comment: @hvgotcodes: No. This is a sad day, I've solved it, but there was an ugly error elsewhere